# How do I push an image to my NON-public repo in dockerhub

Tags: docker, push, dockerhub

How do I push to a non-public repository on dockerhub?

Suppose the account is called “myaccount” and the (non-public) repo is called “myrepo”. In the repo page it says, “Pull this repository: docker pull myaccount/myrepo”.

E.g., suppose I have an image called “myrepo/myimage”. I have logged into my account (`sudo docker login`), and tried,

```
sudo docker push docker.io/myrepo/myimage
sudo docker push myrepo/myimage
sudo docker push myaccout:myrepo/myimage
sudo docker push myaccount/myrepo:myrepo/myimage
sudo docker push myaccount/myrepo:myimage
```

etc.

None of these work. I get errors like "Invalid repository name", or it succeeds but says, "Do you really want to push to public registry?" - and I do not - I want to push it to my non-public dockerhub repo ("myaccount/myrepo").

Answer (score 0):

Please tag your image first as `myaccount/myrepo:<tag-name>` locally using 
`docker tag <your-local-image> myaccount/myrepo:<tag-name>` and then try 
`docker push myaccount/myrepo:<tag-name>`
**Note** Give a valid name for <*tag-name*> like *v1*, *v2*, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I now see that tags are not just for versions. My two images are not different versions - they are totally independent images. So I would not use "v1" and "v2", but rather "SomeImage" and "SomeOtherImage". That's ok - I just did not realize that tags should be used that way. But I tried it, and I logged in, and after pushing I get the error message, "FATA[0006] Repository does not exist: docker.io/<my-account>/<my-repo>. Note that my repo is not public, but it does exist - I am looking at it right now.

Comment: how come docker.io in-front of `<my-account>/<my-repo>` in the error message. You did tag locally as `<my-account>/<my-repo>:<tag-name>`, right?

Comment: I am using Centos, and it turns out that Red Hat has their own version of docker, and it requires that one put "docker.io" in front. What I needed to do was sudo docker tag <image-id> docker.io/<account-name>/<repo-name>:<image-name> and then sudo docker push docker.io/<account-name>/<repo-name>:<image-name>.

Comment: In that case, you might want to replace the docker binary that Red Hat provided with the official docker binary: https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/